# Javascript Form Submission - Undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to recreate a javascript dictionary API project I've seen on youtube. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUkgK7TI0x0&list=PLNCevxogE3fiLT6bEObGeVfHVLnttptKv&index=2)

I tried to use a submit eventListener while one from youtube, he/she used a click event on the button. I already tried that in my previous to-do list project which I solved with the help of this community (thanks to you all). When I press enter or click the button, I always get undefined. I want to fully understand what went wrong to improve my coding skills. Any answers I get are definitely a huge help! Thank you! :)

```js
const inputEl = document.querySelector('form');
// const buttonEl = document.querySelector('.search-button')
const url = 'https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/';


inputEl.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const input = inputEl.value;

    console.log(input)

    fetch(`${url}${input}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    })

});
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-weight: normal;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    background-color: #A1CCD1;
}

.container {
    padding: 35px;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    height: 600px;
    width: 500px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

form {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

input {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #302f2fbd;
    border: none;
    width: 75%;
}

input:focus {
    outline: none;
    color: #302f2fbd;
}

.search-button {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 19.1px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.search-button:focus {
    background-color: #ffff;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.result {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 25px;
}

.result h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.result button {
    font-size: 40px;
    border: none;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.answers {
    margin: 30px;
}

.answers h1 {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 30px 0;

}

.answers .other-meaning {
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="input" class="text" placeholder="Type Text Here">
        <button class="search-button">Search</button>
    </form>

    <div class="result">

    <h1>Text</h1>
    <button class="button-sound">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-volume-high"></i>
    </button>
   
    </div>

    <div class="answers">
        <p class="type-of">noun</p>

        <h1 class="meaning">Sample text</h1>
    
        <h1 class="other-meaning">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam, voluptatum quae! Iure, sunt provident nihil ducimus minima ab quaerat eaque 
            maiores ad culpa. Totam dolorem quam quod magni, dicta veniam!
        </h1>

    </div>
```

Comment: Forms don't have values; I think you want to target the specific input: `const inputEl = document.querySelector("input");`

Comment: I already did that. It gets worst. In my previous project to-do list, I targeted the form with submit eventListener and it works. Now that I want to use that also in my search bar for my dictionary app  and when I console.log I get 'undefined' and the dictionary api cant capture what i want to get.

Comment: For cleaner code change the variable name `inputEl` to form or something that relates to a form. This will make it more obvious what that is. Then create a new one called `const inputEl = document.querySelector("input");` like @mykaf mentioned. Then add the submit event to your form variable.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that you need to watch the form element for the submit event, but the form doesn't have a value. You have to access the input element to get the specific value, since a form can have many inputs.

```
const formEl = document.querySelector('form');
const inputEl = document.querySelector('input');
const url = 'https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/';


formEl.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const input = inputEl.value;

    console.log(input)

    fetch(`${url}${input}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a form like this it is always a good idea to use names for all input elements and the form as well. When you have the event listener for the form, the event (`e`) holds information about the form (`e.target`) and now it is easy to get the value if any input element without defining any global variables etc.

For fun I included more markup in the form. So at any place you can insert the `<output>` element (with a name) and it is easy to give that output a value (but I don't think that it scales in your case, because the fetched result can have many items/meanings etc.).

```js
const url = 'https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/';

document.forms.search.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let form = e.target;

  console.log(form.searchtext.value);

  fetch(`${url}${form.searchtext.value}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      let firstresult = data[0];
      form.word.value = firstresult.word;
    })
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: normal;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  background-color: #A1CCD1;
}

.container {
  padding: 35px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  height: 600px;
  width: 500px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

form {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

input {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #302f2fbd;
  border: none;
  width: 75%;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
  color: #302f2fbd;
}

.search-button {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 19.1px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.search-button:focus {
  background-color: #ffff;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.result {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 25px;
}

.result h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.result button {
  font-size: 40px;
  border: none;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.answers {
  margin: 30px;
}

.answers h1 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.answers .other-meaning {
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form name="search">
    <input type="text" name="searchtext" class="text" placeholder="Type Text Here">
    <button type="submit" class="search-button">Search</button>

    <div class="result">

      <h1><output name="word"></output></h1>
      <button class="button-sound"><i class="fa-solid fa-volume-high"></i></button>
    </div>

    <div class="answers">
      <p class="type-of">noun</p>

      <h1 class="meaning">Sample text</h1>

      <h1 class="other-meaning">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam, voluptatum quae! Iure, sunt provident nihil ducimus minima ab quaerat eaque maiores ad culpa. Totam dolorem quam quod magni, dicta veniam!
      </h1>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```